# Link back query not working for ContentBlocksFieldPlugin

Tags: content-management-system, hippocms

I am new to hippo cms so apologies if i am not using correct terminologies.

I have followed this link and got the first query working [cms hippo docs](https://documentation.bloomreach.com/library/concepts/search/search-all-hippodocument-beans-that-have-a-link-to-a-hippodocument-you-have.html)

I have got 2 doctypes Master and Servant respectively.

Master doctype java and yaml file are as follows

```
@HippoEssentialsGenerated(internalName = "website:link")
public List<HippoBean> getLink() {
    return getLinkedBeans("website:link", HippoBean.class);
}
```

yaml code

```
  /link:
    /cluster.options:
      base.path: /content/documents
      jcr:primaryType: frontend:pluginconfig
      last.visited.enabled: true
      nodetypes:
      - website:servant
    caption: Link
    field: link
    hint: ''
    jcr:primaryType: frontend:plugin
    plugin.class: org.hippoecm.frontend.editor.plugins.field.NodeFieldPlugin
    wicket.id: ${cluster.id}.field

  /link:
    hipposysedit:mandatory: false
    hipposysedit:multiple: true
    hipposysedit:ordered: false
    hipposysedit:path: website:link
    hipposysedit:primary: false
    hipposysedit:type: hippo:mirror
    hipposysedit:validators:
    - optional
    jcr:primaryType: hipposysedit:field
```

Master has got linkedbean to link to servant doctype as shown above.

Now in the Servant doctype i would like to show the master details, so i added a query as shown below and it works as expected.

```java
public Master getParentDetails() {
    final HstRequestContext context = RequestContextProvider.get();

    try {
        HstQuery linkedBeanQuery = ContentBeanUtils.createIncomingBeansQuery(
            this.getCanonicalBean(), context.getSiteContentBaseBean(),
            "*/website:link/@hippo:docbase",
            Master.class, false);
        linkedBeanQuery.setLimit(1);
        return (Master) linkedBeanQuery.execute().getHippoBeans().nextHippoBean();
    } catch (QueryException queryException) {
        log.warn("QueryException ", queryException);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem is when i change the plugin class in Master to `plugin.class: org.onehippo.forge.contentblocks.ContentBlocksFieldPlugin` and add compound list `compoundList: website:junior` things stop working and give error.

Note that now the getlink() method and the `link` yaml code shown above is moved into a new compound called junior.

Master is just for allowing multiple compounds of junior with appropriate code as shown below.

```java
@HippoEssentialsGenerated(internalName = "website:servantlink");
public List<HippoBean> getServantlink() {
    return getLinkedBeans("website:servantlink", HippoBean.class);
}
```

yaml code

```
  /servantlink:
    /cluster.options:
      jcr:primaryType: frontend:pluginconfig
      nodetypes:
      - website:servant
    caption: groups
    compoundList: website:junior
    contentPickerType: links
    field: servantlink
    hint: ''
    jcr:primaryType: frontend:plugin
    plugin.class: org.onehippo.forge.contentblocks.ContentBlocksFieldPlugin
    wicket.id: ${cluster.id}.field
    wicket.skin: skin/content-blocks.css
  /servantlink:
    hipposysedit:mandatory: false
    hipposysedit:multiple: true
    hipposysedit:ordered: false
    hipposysedit:path: website:servantlink
    hipposysedit:type: hippo:compound
    hipposysedit:validators:
    - contentblocks-validator
    jcr:primaryType: hipposysedit:fiel
```

So my question is how the query should be now?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally got it working

The master java class should be as follows. Please note use getChildBeansByName instead of getLinkedBeans here.

```
@HippoEssentialsGenerated(internalName = "website:servantlink");
public List<HippoBean> getServantlink() {
    return getChildBeansByName("website:servantlink");
}
```

No changes in the master.yaml its all good.
Now the query part in Servant java class should be as follows.

```
    final HstRequestContext context = RequestContextProvider.get();

    try {
        HstQuery linkedBeanQuery = ContentBeanUtils.createIncomingBeansQuery(
            this.getCanonicalBean(), context.getSiteContentBaseBean(),
            "website:servantlink/website:link/@hippo:docbase",
            Master.class, false);
        linkedBeanQuery.setLimit(1);
        return (Master) linkedBeanQuery.execute().getHippoBeans().nextHippoBean();
    } catch (QueryException queryException) {
        log.warn("QueryException ", queryException);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The most important part is this `website:servantlink/website:link/@hippo:docbase`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the new situation, you're creating compounds of type website:junior that have the link. So in the incoming beans query, change "*/website:link/@hippo:docbase" accordingly.

Hope that helps,
Jeroen

Comment: Thanks, but i had the same query as you are suggesting. please check above